# Кеширование на сайте

Tags: javascript, php, css, html5

Каждый раз когда я что-то изменяю в css или js файле не происходят изменения на сайте из-за кеширования. Чтобы увидеть изменения нужно переименовать файл. Можно к концу дописать цифры css?92863. Как при каждом сохранении автоматически менять эти цифры?

Comment: Если такие изменения происходят только при разработке, то достаточно перезагрузить страницу через `Ctrl` + `F5` или отключить кэш в `DevTools` (`F12 -> Network -> Disable cache`).

Comment: Не только у меня такое. А как можно каждый раз новое название делать? Цифры менять в конце

Comment: Если это "темплейт" в .php файле то можно как-то так, к примеру: `<script src="/script.js?<?= date('ymdhis') ?>"></script>`

Comment: Или так ?v=<?= filemtime('путь до ассета'); ?>

Comment: Это я сменю путь. А как и название файла менять при каждом сохранении?